# How should a service exit to prevent an error?

Tags: c#, .net, service

I'm developing a Windows service in C#, .NET 6.0 following the instructions on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service  The service runs as expected, but when I stop the service, it logs an error

> A task was canceled.
>
> Exception:
> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
> at AWLService.WindowsBackgroundService.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) in C:\Minerva\Projects\AWLService_Test\WindowsBackgroundService.cs:line 22

The ExecuteAsync for this program is as follows:

```
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                string joke = _jokeService.GetJoke();
                _logger.LogWarning("{Joke}", joke);

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), stoppingToken);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "{Message}", ex.Message);

            // Terminates this process and returns an exit code to the operating system.
            // This is required to avoid the 'BackgroundServiceExceptionBehavior', which
            // performs one of two scenarios:
            // 1. When set to "Ignore": will do nothing at all, errors cause zombie services.
            // 2. When set to "StopHost": will cleanly stop the host, and log errors.
            //
            // In order for the Windows Service Management system to leverage configured
            // recovery options, we need to terminate the process with a non-zero exit code.
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }
```

I've tried catching TaskCanceledException.  When I do that and add Environment.Exit(0), I still get the error.  If I take out Environment.Exit, the service terminates without an error, but it logs "Service stopped successfully" twice.

What is the proper way I should be ending my service?

Thank you.

EDIT:
I added a handler for TaskCanceledException as follows:

```
catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
{
    //Do nothing, we're exiting normally.
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

When I do that, stopping the service through MMC shows an error "Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly" and a message is not logged indicating the service was stopped.  Stopping it with sc on the command line doesn't show an error, but it also doesn't log a message that the service was stopped.

If I remove the `Environment.Exit(0)` line, MMC no longer shows an error, but the "Service stopped successfully" log message is written twice.

Comment: In your `OperationCancelledException` handler, were you still logging the exception to the console?

Comment: IMHO trigger a graceful `IHost` shutdown via `IHostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();` at the end of your `ExecuteAsync` method.  Otherwise you may lose log output. Then return `Environment.ExitCode` from your `Main()` to indicate failure.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the `OperationCancelledException` and log something different to the console in the handler. I suspect in your original handler (not shown) you were still probably doing this: `_logger.LogError(ex, "{Message}", ex.Message);`

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    try
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            string joke = _jokeService.GetJoke();
            _logger.LogWarning("{Joke}", joke);

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), stoppingToken);
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCancelledException)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("The service has stopped");
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "{Message}", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: My `OperationCancelledException` handler isn't doing any logging.  I tried doing `Environment.Exit(0)` in the handler, but when I stopped the service through MMC, it caused an "Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly".  With Exit(0) in the handler, stopping it with sc from the command line doesn't report an error, but it also doesn't log a message that the service was stopped.  If I take out the `Environment.Exit(0)`, I no longer get an error from MMC, but it logs "Service stopped successfully" twice.

Comment: I'm actually using `TaskCanceledException`, not `OperationCanceledException`, but I get the same results for both.